# three.js orbital controls reset by animating

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there any way to set the angle of three.js orbital controls angle. When t try to setAzimuthalAngle and polar angle it shows

```
controls.setPolarAngle(myangle)

controls.setPolarAngle is not a function
```

I need a way so that i can tween the cameras angle to 0.

Answer (score 0):

As you note, there is no `setPolarAngle` function for [OrbitControls.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js). You probably want to change the min/max values for vertical orbiting instead to lock it at your desired angle.

```
// How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
// Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians
```